# get computer description from computer in network

Tags: vb.net

i have a list of Hostnames from computers in my network and now i want to know how i can get the computer-description from these computers.

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string name = 
    System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("localhost").HostName
```

Comment: This returns the host name of the local machine. I don't think that this is what Nico asked for...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution but a few pointers that might help you get going.

In general, you can access the computer description using **WMI**, in particular, by getting `\\nameOfTheRemoteComputer\root\cimv2`, executing `SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem` and querying the `Description` property.

- Here is an example in "old" VB accessing this data: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=344879, and
- here is an example of accessing WMI with VB.NET: http://nishantpant.files.wordpress.com/2006/11/wmivb.txt.

By combining these examples, you should get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

All these methods use PowerShell -

You could use a one-liner.

gwmi -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | select-object Description

Remote computer.

gwmi -computer computername -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | select-object Description

Remote computer, passing credentials.

gwmi -computer computername -credentials domain\username -query "select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem" | select-object Description

Or from the registry

$Machine = "MachineToCheck"
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$Machine)
$regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("System\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters")
$regkey.GetValue("srvcomment")